# rxjava flatmap giving error in retrofit Response

Tags: java, android, rx-java

LoginResponse and LoginRequest are my model class. and i display error
Response class is from retrofit library and really cant solve this. Rxjava flatmap Func1 to retrofit.Response class.

```
public Observable<LoginResponse> performLogin(String emailId, String password) {

    LoginRequest requestBody = new LoginRequest(emailId,password);
    Log.d("LoginRequestBody",requestBody.getLoginId());

    return mSamparkService.performLogin(requestBody)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<LoginResponse>, Observable<LoginResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<LoginResponse> call(Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                    //TODO: remove sensitive debug logs
                    Timber.d("status code: %s", response.code());
                    Timber.d("body: %s", response.body());
                    Timber.d("error body: %s", response.errorBody());
                    Timber.d("message: %s", response.message());

                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG,"in dtl attnd switch case");
                        switch (response.code()) {
                            case 200:


                                return Observable.just(response.body());
                            case 401:
                            case 403:
                                return Observable.error(new UnauthorizedException(response.errorBody().string()));
                            default:
                                return Observable.empty();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Timber.e(e, "error while signIn");
                        return Observable.error(e);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong type for the first input-param of Func1. The pictures shows, that flatMap Func1 expects LoginResponse as first input-param. You are using Response<LoginResponse>. In order to resolve this issue, just change the type of Func1 to LoginResponse.

Comment: Yup Thank you.it was silly of me.